# apply authenicate method on all routers in express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, http-status-code-401

I'm very new to node.

I want to apply custom authentication using `passport.js` to `all router`.

using this example. -> https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-http-bearer-example

the code below is my server/index.js.

```
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const index = require('./routes/index.js');
    const downloadRouter = require('./routes/fileDownload.js');

    const app = express();

    app.disable("x-powered-by");

    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));



    app.set("src", path.join(__dirname, "../src"));



    var passport = require('passport');
    var Strategy = require('passport-http-bearer').Strategy;
    var db = require('./adminDB');

    passport.use(new Strategy(
      function(token, cb) {
        db.users.findByToken(token, function(err, user) {
          if (err) { return cb(err); }
          if (!user) { return cb(null, false); }
          return cb(null, user);
        });
      }));

    // app.use('/api-test', passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false 
     }), function(req, res) {
    //     res.json({ username: req.user.username, value: 
          req.user.emails[0].value });
    //     res.end(); 
    //   });

    app.use('*', passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }), 
       function(req, res, next) {
           console.log("api all before action")
      if(!err) {
        next();
      } else {
        res.status(401).end();
      }
    });

    app.use('/download', downloadRouter);



    const { PORT = 8080 } = process.env;
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)); 

    // export default app;
```

what I want to ask is this part.

The annotated `api-test` parts handles authenication very well. However, the "app.use(*)" part does not handle it. console.log is also not working. Returns 200, regardless of the certification procedure, outputting the original screen(index.html).

How do I authenticate across all my routers and get all of my screens back to their original output?

Answer (score 0):

I leave an answer because there may be someone in a similar situation.

```
app.use('*', passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }), function(req, res, next) {
  next();
});
```

put this code, upper then router code.